# How to wait untill all threadings will be closed?

Tags: python, multithreading

I use dynamic output in console and I have table with overall information about the dynamic data. With use threading like:

```
for i in list:
   th = threading.Thread(target=function_name, args=(i,))
   print(f'Thread named {th.getName()} is started')
   th.start()
```

A dynamic content in random parts of the table is present (it is no needed any dynamic content in table)
I suppose, i must to wait until last `th` will be done, but how to do so? If I'll add string `th.join()` after `th.start()`, it will make no sense because I see, that it is no multithreading, but launched sequentially.

Comment: Add all started threads to a list, out side of the loop where you start all the threads loop over the list of threads doing `th.join()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give a name to the thread and check if it's still active before continuing. Something like:

```
from time import sleep
import threading

for i in list:
   th = threading.Thread(target=function_name, args=(i), name="dload")
   print(f'Thread named {th.getName()} is started')
   th.start()
   while any(x.getName() for x in threading.enumerate() if "dload" == x.getName()):
       sleep(1) # or even a lower value: sleep(0.05)
```

Comment: Is it harmful for multithreading? Will the program wait an extra second every time after that?

Comment: there's nothing harmful on the code, specially having a sleep delay better the threads enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create all the threads in list without starting them.

Then iterate over the list and start all the threads.

And eventually iterate again and join them all.

Another option is to use `ThreadPoolExecutor`

Comment: Like this:
    runned_threads = []
    for i in list:
       th = threading.Thread(target=function_name, args=(i,))
       print(f'Thread named {th.getName()} is started')
       th.start()
       runned_threads.append(th)

    for i in runned_threads:
        i.join()